# Docker Inter-container communication without port number

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have 2 docker containers(container name : A & B) on 1 host & they are connected to same user-defined bridge(test-bridge).
**Target state/Trying to achieve:**
To be able to call container B from container A via hostname only & not hostname:port.
**Current State:**
I am able to call API's hosted inside container B via url http://{{containerName:portNumber} i.e. http://B:6000 from container A.
 I want to get rid of the port number because IMO being connected on the same network along-with the container name should be sufficient enough to resolve the request to target container.
Is there a way for inter-container communication via this approach

**UPDATE**
 Still looking for a solution as the package that I am working on would be a core utility(at-least 3 containers), this would be deployed with other docker apps. The port number 80 would only help 1 container only but to call other utilities the caller would need to attach port number that I can't expose as it is an infra/network level information.

Comment: The port is also essential information because 6000 is a non-standard HTTP port (standard is 80). If it was 80, you could omit it, and for HTTPS you could omit port 443. Your service has no way of knowing the API is listening at port 6000 in the other container.

Comment: hmm..I was expecting if the name of the container is already present that too on the same network it can be easily extracted/identified by docker & it would have saved the trouble of hardcoding the port in url

Comment: If hardcoding the port is the issue, then set it in a variable and use that var in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP default port (80) and then you won't have to specify it.

Change your app B to listen on port 80 - then you'll be able to call `http://B` without adding port number.